# Delphi FMX 3D Scene multi object selection code example (selection rectangle)

Tags: delphi, 3d, firemonkey

I'd like to know is there any intrinsic method in FMX to select single or multiple objects in 3D Scene, preferably with selection rectangle?

Say that, I've many objects(spehere, cube, complex mesh etc.) in 3D Scene(Vivewport3D) and I want to select them with selection rectangle or each one individually. Code example will be really appreciated.